# Interpreting conflicting Regression Results

Tags: regression, linear-regression

I have a bit of a question regarding interpreting regression coefficients. Let's say for example I have data which covers a three week period of time, and that I have a simple linear equations as follows:

`y ~ x`

Let's say I run the regression over this three week period of time such that for the coefficient of `x` I find that it is equal to `0.0032` for the whole period.

Now, let's say I want to divide up the period and run the regression per week instead, so that for Week 1 for `x` I obtain the coefficient `0.00977`, for Week 2 I obtain `0.02877`, and for Week 3 I obtain `0.00318`.

I'm a little confused by this, Week 1 has less data compared to Week 2 and Week 3, but Week 2 and 3 have pretty much the same amount of data, so I'm not sure why the regression results for Week 3 are very similar to the overall regression results over the whole period. Can anyone provide any ideas of why this might be the case? Naturally since I haven't provided any data it would impossible fore anyone to give me the exact reason, but I'm mostly looking for some ideas for why I'm obtaining these results, and whether perhaps there's a way to measure or account for this phenomena. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest visual inspection and comparison of scatterplots for each regression's data set.

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured, I was hoping there might be an alternative method since my data is a bit tricky to plot in a meaningful way. Thanks!

Comment: Just an idea: You could add week indicators (each week gets an own intercept) to control for unobserved variation across weeks. Say y=x+w1+w2. You can also allow for individual slopes per week, y=x+w1x+w1+w2x+w2. This allows you to test if the estimated coefficients are different per week. So you can get an idea of what the DGP is. Drilling up linear models like this sometimes helps to understand the structure of the data and to see if estimates are robust.